# How to troubleshoot pipeline for performance issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, solrnet

I created a test page that just displays the word Test. Time to first byte is almost 3 seconds.

I made a change to the project, recompiled, and hit my test page 1st and then it only took a few milliseconds. Went to home page and login page and back to test page and still only a few seconds.

Then I went to a category search page (powered by solr) and back to my test page. Now my test page takes almost 3 seconds to load again. So something about the category pages is doing something that adds close to 3 seconds to all requests.

I'm going to start looking through the category pages and seeing what might be the problem, however I just happened to realize by chance that the category pages were the problem (actually... I suppose I can't prove that they are the problem yet but common sense seams to dictate they are based on above experience). If I hadn't realized that, how would I even go about troubleshooting an issue like this since 3 seconds is not being caused by any user code that I can debug?

Comment: Inspect the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: @Wheels73 You mean in the browser? If so then there's nothing going on there... it's all server side processing.

Comment: For my test page there is only the one line for the page itself which takes about 3 seconds for ttfb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy app like fiddler to intercept the call between your server and solr, and see whats happening. A lot of things could happen, so first you have to isolate the query to solr and see if it's the problem or you have to search in other places.

Comment: On my test page there are no such requests showing up in the network activity. I wouldn't imagine I'd find anything in fiddler if they aren't there either. I'll check it out though and see if I find anything.